# How can AlphaZero be used in other industries besides gaming?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, deep-rl, applications, monte-carlo-tree-search, alphazero

I'm an AI Engineering student from Belgium and I'm writing my bachelor thesis on the creation of a chess computer with deep reinforcement learning based on AlphaZero. My implementation can be found here: https://github.com/zjeffer/chess-deep-rl.

To complete my thesis, I'd like to know more about AlphaZero's use in other industries. It seems that so far, AlphaGo, AlphaGo Zero and AlphaZero have primarily been used for solving games.

How can AlphaZero and Monte Carlo Tree Search be used in other industries besides the games industry?

I've looked at [this question](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/3502/2444), but it's more general - I would like to know specifically about AlphaZero and MCTS applications.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at it basically, considering these are made to oppose the human player or AI player in a strategy game, I would look at other aspects of life that have military-like components and a vs kind of dynamic, e.g. utilised in war, in computer games and things like this. Perhaps crowd control could be one in terms of strategical thinking it could try to adapt using strategy to such 'chaotic movements. I know it is not a very specific answer but I think I have touched on some good points that can lead to finding more papers on the subject.